# Windows 7 Excel 2010 annoying personal.xlsb message

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm running Windows 7. Each time I run Excel I get this message popping up.

> Excel cannot open the file '~$PERSONAL.XSLB' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

I should also add that the file does exist.

I just want to turn the notification off.

Comment: Have you searched for that filename? I would delete it if it isn't needed. You also may want to start Excel in safe mode and see if the problem persists: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/work-with-office-safe-modes-HP010354300.aspx

Comment: You've edited your post to include your solution - I would instead post your solution as an Answer with detail on how you were able to get the necessary permissions to access that file (on which OS exactly?) and choose your Answer as correct. This will help others who stumble across this question who have a similar problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permission issue, I didn't have full permission to the folder where '~$PERSONAL.XSLB' resided in. So no need to delete the file.

Answer (score 1):

I have Excel 2013, and was having the exact warning window every time I opened Excel.  At some point a default Personal.xslb file was made, as I inadvertently clicked on something wrong while making a Macro, or in Visual Basic.  I tried to delete the Macro, but it stated the workbook associated with it was hidden.  Go to View > Unhide [window] and it opened the offended .xslb file that I could not find.  Then go back to delete the Macro [Developer > Macros > delete].  It worked perfectly.  Save your changes.  I went a step further and just deleted the file entirely.  I found it by going to File > Info > Open File Location [bottom right].  It opened the folder on my desktop and I found I also had a auto-saved version in there.  I deleted both.  No more pop-up.